# How do I pass a parameter to a form partial that is shown via CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So my form partial is loaded in my `div id="secondary"`, which is hidden on first page load.

When the user hits a button with a class called `toggleSidebar`, then the `_form.html.erb` is shown.

I have overridden the partial to display a new form (even if `update` is pressed) when a user is not logged in like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(Post.new, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

As opposed to the regular version that looks like this, and is included in an `if` statement on this same partial:

```
<% if current_user and current_user.has_any_role? :editor, :admin %>
    <%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

The real issue is in my view, when someone goes to `Update`, this is what happens when the user is logged out:

```
 <%= link_to "Update", "#", class: "togglesidebar" %>
```

This is perfect, it executes the CSS and shows the empty form partial perfectly.

However, when a user is logged in, I want it to send the parameter `parent_id: @post` with the execution of the sidebar being toggled.

This is how it looks with a normal `new_post_path` view (i.e. the non-sidebar new post view):

```
<% if current_user %>                                    
     <%= link_to "Update", new_post_path(parent_id: @post) %>
<% end %>
```

This is what my `PostController#New` looks like:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
  end
```

How do I either pass the params in the regular non `new_post_path` version, or tackle this another way?

Comment: Hey, the question is confusing. It would help if you share your complete code.

Comment: What are you using to "execute the CSS?" Is it just a javascript hook that says to toggle visibility for a given target or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use a helper method.

Just browse to the 'helper' directory under 'app' folder and create a file similar to [name]_helper.rb

In this file create a module by [name]Helper and declare your helper method in this module.

This module is automatically required by rails.

A small example might help you.

The code in the link_helper.rb under app/helper directory

```html
module LinkHelper

  def populate_link(link1, link2, parameter)
    if current_user
      public_send(link2, parameter)
    else
      link1
    end
  end

end
```

The code in views is

```html
<%= link_to 'update', populate_link('#', 'new_requirement_path',parameter: 33) %>
```

Comment: This is genius. Thanks much. I think this is the perfect use of helpers and it actually. I have always wanted to use helpers, but never saw the need - until now, I think I just levelled up in my Rails-fu. Thanks much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I apply a class to the link? Either the `link2` or `link1` in this case? Assume I want to apply two different classes depending on the link. How might I do that?

Comment: @marcamillion you could use a helper again for this. for eg:
<%= link_to 'update', populate_link('#', 'new_requirement_path',parameter: 33), class: apply_class(args) %>
Note: the method apply_class should return a string.
P.S. I haven't tried this in practical, please let me know if this class applying method work.
Glad, my answer helped

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by the question, but I think you may be just need to use a hidden field to pass the parent_id param back?

e.g./

```
<%= simple_form_for(Post.new, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, { value: @post.try(:id) } %>
<% end %>
```

HTH?

Comment: What would happen when `:parent_id` is nil? Would this gracefully fail?

Answer (score 1):

I am also a bit confused, but the following railscast might help you. It shows how to embed data in an html-tag. You can probably do it the same way. 
[railscast-> passing data to javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

Out of the possibilities there I'd recommend the data-attribute:

```
<%= simple_form_for,(Post.new, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }, **data: {post_id: @post.id}**) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```